# Expected value of sin(X) for Gamma r.v. X in closed form (approximation is fine)

Tags: pr.probability, na.numerical-analysis

I have a random variable $X \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$.

How can I compute or approximate $\mathbb{E} \sin(X)$ very quickly? Iterative quadrature would be too slow, I need some closed form expression.

One idea I considered was to use the Gamma moments and Tyler approximation, but it would take too many terms, since $X$ has large standard deviation (in the order of 10–50) and so the mass is not tightly concentrated.

Comment: MathOverflow is for mathematicians to ask each other questions about their research. See Math.StackExchange to ask general questions in mathematics.

Comment: It seems that sometimes $X\sim\operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$ means $$ 
\Pr(X\in S) = \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_S \left( \frac x \beta \right) e^{-x/\beta} \, \left( \frac{dx} \beta\right) \quad \text{for } S\subseteq [0,+\infty) $$ and sometimes it means $$ \Pr(X\in S) = \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_S (\beta x) e^{-\beta x} (\beta\,dx) \quad \text{for } S\subseteq[0,+\infty). $$ To say which you have in mind might be convenient. $\qquad$

Comment: I would first try writing $(\sin x) e^{-x/\beta}$ as $\operatorname{Im} \left( e^{-x/\beta + ix} \right). \qquad$

Comment: This seems a perfectly legitimate question for this site, unless one believes approximation theory and error analysis are somehow not "mathematical research"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the characteristic function.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), we have $$E[e^{itX}] = 
\left(1 - \frac{it}{\beta} \right)^{-\alpha}.$$

You have to be a bit careful when $\alpha$ isn't an integer, as you have a branch cut.

This means that $E[\sin(X)] = \operatorname{Im}\left[ \left(1 - \beta^{-1} i \right)^{-\alpha} \right]$.  Writing $1 - \beta^{-1}i = r e^{i \theta}$ with $r = (1 + \beta^{-2})^{1/2}$ and $\theta = -\arctan(\beta^{-1})$ gives \begin{align}
\operatorname E[ \sin(X)] & = r^{-\alpha} \operatorname{Im}(e^{-i\theta \alpha}) \\[8pt]
& = (1 + \beta^{-2})^{-\alpha/2} \sin\left(\alpha \arctan(\beta^{-1}) \right).
\end{align}